# Algorithm to solve combination without repetition

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations

I i’m look of for an algorithm to solve this exercise

There are 6 bunnies
There are 6 holes:
- In The first hole there is a yellow carrot 
- In The second an orange carrot
- In The third a blue carrot
- In the fourth a yellow carrot
- In the fifth an orange carrot
- In The sixth a blue carrot

Each bunny has to eat only One carrot of each type (One yellow, One orange and one blue)

The bunnies have to Enter in the holes in groups of three

Find the way in which there is The less number of repetition (if bunny 1 eats the yellow carrot with bunny 2 and 3 and then eats the blue carrot with bunny 3 and 4 it is considered a repetition because The bunny 1 encountered bunny 3, two times)

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: I’ve managed to find all possibile combination of These k (6) element in groups of r (3). 
I’ve also managed to eliminate all the duplicates like 123 321 132
But i don’t know how to find The best way to obtain The less number of repetition and accomplish the request of have every bunny to eating One carrot of every type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an pen and paper approach and write all combination with the first three carrots/colors and then for the next.

As result, you see for each bunny all colors in a column.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6    bunnies
a b c d e f    carrots


a b c          combinations at same time
  a b c
    a b c
      a b c
c       a b 
b c       a

d e f          basically the same as for a b c
  d e f
    d e f
      d e f
f       d e
e f       d
```

After this grouping, you could write now an algorithm